# How do I setup JBoss EAP6 with Kerberos authentication?

Tags: kerberos, jboss-eap-6

I have a JBoss EAP6 and want to setup Kerberos authentication with our Active Directory infrastructure. What configuration goes into `web.xml`, `jboss-web.xml` and `standalone.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

In `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>My Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/context-to-protect/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>AD_Group_Name</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
    <realm-name>SPNEGO</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>Allowed Users</description>
    <role-name>AD_Group_Name</role-name>
</security-role>
```

In `jboss-web.xml`, residing next to `web.xml`:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/SPNEGO</security-domain>
    <valve>
        <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>
    </valve>
    <jacc-star-role-allow>true</jacc-star-role-allow>
</jboss-web>
```

In your `pom.xml` you may need some dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-negotiation-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8.Final-redhat-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-security-spi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.SP2</version>
    </dependency>
```

In `standalone.xml`:

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <!-- all your other extensions -->
</extensions>
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.security.krb5.realm" value="mydomain.com"/>
    <property name="java.security.krb5.kdc" value="kdcserver.mydomain.com"/>
    <!-- all your other properties -->
</system-properties>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="host">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="keyTab" value="/path/to/your/server.keytab"/>
                        <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/server.mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="requisite">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="AdvancedAdLdap" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=MyCN,OU=MyOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="bindCredential" value="thepassword"/>
                        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ldap.mydomain.com:389"/>
                        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="OU=MyOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="OU=MyOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                        <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                        <module-option name="recurseRoles" value="true"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="LdapDomain" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ldap.mydomain.com:389"/>
                        <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=MyCN,OU=MyOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="bindCredential" value="thepassword"/>
                        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="OU=MyOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="CN=MyCN,OU=MyOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
                        <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                        <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```